# Como criar classe JPA apartir de um relacionamento N para N

Tags: java

Boa tarde Galera, no meu trabalho de java Web tenho duas tabelas onde o relacionamento é ManyToMany, então fui ao banco de dados, criei uma terceira tabela com a chave das outras duas, porém na hora de gerar as entidades através do banco de dados, não funciona, alguém poderia me dar um help? obrigado.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: sua pergunta ficou um pouco superficial, não deu para entender direito o seu problema/duvida

Comment: entao Brumazzi, tenho uma tabela no banco chamada exames_cadastrados, com a chave IdExame referenciando a tabela exame a chave idCliente referenciando a tabela cliente, idExame e idCliente na tabela exames_cadastrados são chaves estrangeiras que formam uma chave primária composta, e na hora que eu mando criar a classe apartir dessas configurações no banco, dá aquele erro acima..queria saber como devo proceder quando uma relação é de n para n.. como fazer isso no JPA?

Comment: creio que você terá q criar a classe manualmente, pelo alerta, parece que o JPA não tem suporte para fazer a junção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para criar essa tabela você precisa antes um objeto que contém um Id para uma entidade (EmbeddedId).
Por exemplo:

```
@Embeddable
public class ExamesCadastradosPK {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="EXCA_EXAM_ID", referencedColumnName="EXAM_ID")
    private Exame exame;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="EXCA_CLIE_ID", referencedColumnName="CLIE_ID")
    private Cliente cliente;

    // getters e setters
}
```

Esse objeto possui as duas chaves da tabela que quer fazer a junção, mas ela não é uma entidade. Note a anotação @Embeddable. Agora crie um objeto que utiliza esse Embeddable como chave primária:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="exames_cadastrados")
public class ExamesCadastrados {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ExamesCadastradosPK examesCadastradosPK;

    // getters e setters
}
```